# Framework with charts for mobile web application

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, charts

I'm working on a mobile web application I need to represent some data in a pie chart however I don't found any good framework that offer a good option and works fine on a mobile device, I would like to know some frameworks(free) that can help me.
I will be amazed if you can give some basics examples, I'm thinking use ajax technology for show the charts.

Comment: I forgot, this must be compatible with android, iOS and BlackBerry's OS

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if any of these fit your needs:

- http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/charts
- http://www.zingchart.com/
- http://code.google.com/apis/chart/
- http://code.google.com/p/flot/
- http://www.highcharts.com/
- http://www.splashnology.com/article/15-awesome-free-javascript-charts/325/

Comment: Do you know if they are compatible with Android, Blackberry and iOS?

Comment: most if not all are HTML5 and jQuery/JavaScript which should be compatible for most if not all smart phones with HTML5 compatible browsers

Comment: if you need an open source solution I would recommend flot. If you can put up some $'s go with highcharts. I haven't used Sencha charts before - they look good but you'll probably have to learn the Extjs way