# comparison jquery mobile kendo sencha jqtouch

Tags: jquery-mobile, jqtouch, kendo-ui, dhtmlx

i am new in all mobile app thinks i want to find a library for graphs witch it will play in all types of mobiles(ios, android,windows phone etc).I am searching but there are so many and i confused.jquery mobile,kendo,sencha,jqtouch,web 2.0, dhtmlx and so many other. I want my app play in all mobiles, do anyone known the best library. I already have used the libraries i mention before but if there is something else to test and see please tell me.

this is some of the links i saw until now:

http://docs.dhtmlx.com

http://web20boom.com/web/touch.php

I will use phonegap. Please anything it would be very useful.

Maybe my question wasn't very clear and i am sorry for that. I want a JavaScript library for building HTML5-based mobile web apps.I want to make all the beauties in my app (buttons, panel and etc.) I don't want to make graphs i want a library which i can used to make carousels,accordions and other simple and little more difficult thinks.But until now all the libs i saw it doesn't work well in all the phones.Thats why i am asking if there is a library who plays well everywhere.But thanks a lot for your answer.

For example i want a lib like jquery mobile but i want to play well in ios and android phones at least.If anyone know any lib please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if any of these fit your needs:

- http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/charts
- http://www.zingchart.com/
- http://code.google.com/apis/chart/
- http://code.google.com/p/flot/
- http://www.highcharts.com/
- http://www.splashnology.com/article/15-awesome-free-javascript-charts/325/
- http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/
- http://www.jqplot.com/

Related:

- [Framework with charts for mobile web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323343/framework-with-charts-for-mobile-web-application)